# Find all the modified svn files and copy files modified in the same folder structure

Tags: grep, find, file-copy, subversion

I get all the modified svn files using `svn st | grep ^M` command

```
M       student/includes/class_student_promotion.php
M       student/includes/class_student_report.php
M       student/resources/js/student_co_scholistic_activities.js
M       staff/php/edit_staff_details.php
M       library/includes/class_book_return.php
M       library/includes/class_book_item_stock_entry.php
M       library/includes/class_library_common_function.php
M       library/includes/auto_book_name_list.php
M       library/includes/class_book_issue.php
M       library/php/book_item_details_entry.php
M       includes/connection.php
M       includes/links.php
M       staff_student/php/student_time_table.php
M       assignment/php/ajax_created_assignment_report.php
M       assignment/php/ajax_submitted_assignment_report.php
M       student_attendance/php/date_wise_attendance_summary_report.php
M       student_attendance/resources/js/holiday_master.js
```

and my requirement is I want the files listed in the output to be copied in the same folder structure. Like  includes folder to be created and just the files listed in the `svn st` must be copied.

This command

```
cp `svn st | ack '^M' | cut -b 8-` backup
```

can copy all the modified files to a directory but What I expect is I want the folders holding the modified files should also be created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that with folder you mean directory and assuming you have no spaces or special characters in your file and directory names:

```
svn st | ack '^M' | cut -b 8- | cpio -pdmv backup
```

This is `cpio` in pass-through mode (`-p`). It takes a list of filenames to copy from stdin. `-d` allows it to create directories, `-m` preserves modification times and `-v` makes it verbose. Any filenames on stdin are copied to the destination directory, `student/includes/class_student_promotion.php` will be copied to `backup/student/includes/class_student_promotion.php`

Comment: Worked like a charm ...!!!

Comment: @Danny Good to hear that. I removed the [Solved] on your post's title, as the fact that it is solved is indicated, on this site, by a question having an accepted answer.

Comment: what if I want to copy the files starting with M as well as A also..How can I pass multiple values...

Comment: @Danny that is something that your `ack '^M'` needs to handle. I don't have that command on my system, and no idea what it is doing. Post a new question referring to this one.

Comment: Use `cpio -pdmvu` to overwrite files if you're getting "not created: newer or same age version exists" (assuming that's what you want!). Useful when copying files from one checkout to a newly created one.

Comment: Also I tried the tip but it didn't work originally, I had to adjust the `cut` arguments to `cut -b 9-` as it seems my `svn status` has slightly different column alignments